# Freeing Space in an Array by setting element to null?

Tags: java, android, arrays

if i have many Bitmap Objects in an Array
 eg:

```
BitmapArray[ Bitmap1 , Bitmap2 ,Bitmap3, Bitmap4, Bitmap5,...]
```

this will end up taking much stack space (or heap space?) if the array gets big.

My question is now if I   null  the Bitmaps that I dont need anymore, is this freeing space from the stack(or heap)?

```
BitmapArray[ Bitmap1 ,null,null, Bitmap4,null,...]
```

I cannot remove the element and change the array size btw

Comment: What you are looking for is an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). It is a dynamically increasing array. So, you don't need to fix the size.

Comment: its not about the array size, its about the memory usage

Comment: Yes: `myarray[i] = null;` allows GC to free the object you assigned to "myarray[i]".  And yes: a (variable) "List" container like "ArrayList" sounds like it might be more appropriate than a (fixed) "array"

Comment: @user1886411.. I thought your real problem is fixed size array. And you should really use an `ArrayList`. Apart form that, if you nullify the references in your `array`, then the object may be Garbage Collected, provided, you don't have any other reference to your object.

Comment: Setting references to `null` will indeed make the reference "unreachable", therefore freeable by the GC. However, this is Java, this is the JVM and this is the JIT; so, if you highlighted what you wanted to do, a better solution is likely to come across. And always remind that the JIT is smarter than you ;)

Comment: The problem is I cant use the ArrayList.Remove[index] because it would copy all element if i remove index 0 for example. For the dynamic size i agree to use the ArrayList.

Comment: Objects live in the heap. Their references used inside a method are loaded to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't keep holding *any* other references to the bitmaps this can reduce your memory usage. If the bitmaps are not referenced anymore the garbage collector can destroy the unused objects and release the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Nice looking solution for this bitmap-memory problem is LRUCache (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)

It's usefull tool to protect your app from reserving too much memory for bitmaps.

But if you still want to use array - **remember about using .recycle()** on Bitmap before setting the reference to null. Also use System.gc() after releasing memory!

Answer (score 0):

Take the help of Collection like ArrayList

suppose bitmapList is your list of Bitmaps then you can use the index to remove it like

```
bitmapList.remove(indexValue);
```

Comment: i already know this, thx. but if i remove index 0 for example the whole array gets copied

Comment: @user1886411 while array comes from, i m telling u to use arraylist as the container of bitmaps.got it ?

Comment: yeah for the dynamic size...got it

Comment: my problem is not the array size, but the memory usage of the object. and if i use less memory when i null an object. i cant use the remove command beacuse it would copy all elements which would take too long

Comment: @user1886411 on in that case setting null will free the memory for sure.

Comment: "i cant use the remove command" - You must be joking. Of course all array elements may be copied by this, but you do notice that these are only the *references* to your bitmaps? Copying a couple of hundreds of array entries will hardly affect your performance.

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap objects are stored on the heap. If you null the reference in the array and there is no other reference then the object is likely to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to talk about arrays , consider using [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)  .

if you use it for caching , consider using a better caching mechanism that will consider the size of the bitmaps so that it will never take too much space . such a mechanism could be the [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) , which is also included in the compatability library and in the [bitmapFun](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) example .